# Should recent controversial question about Zeitgeist and pop culture be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, answered-questions, vote-to-close

Recently there was a question that some interpreted as a rant:

- [What is zeitgeist used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180990/ubuntu-and-zeitgeist)

This question now has [a good answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/180994/22949) (written by one of the people who had voted to close it, which by itself often means the question's status has changed and it should be considered for reopening).

More importantly, **it has essentially been [resolved here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3988/22949) that the question is, at least in its current form, a real, answerable question, appropriate for our site.**

There's not just one moderator who seems to have said this; **[this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180990/ubuntu-and-zeitgeist#comment225317_180990) by [jrg](https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg) seems to assert the same thing.**

Essentially, what happened is that the OP asked if there is any connection between the software Zeitgeist (which is an important part of Ubuntu) and the popular film series *Zeitgeist*. In some earlier versions of the question, it had sounded like the OP was posting to argue that Ubuntu was possibly unsuitable for use by (some) Christians, depending on the meaning of the package `zeitgeist`. That it was closed is thus quite understandable, as Ask Ubuntu is not a good place for such debates. However, it turns out that **fundamentally the OP wanted to know the answer to a simple question of fact--why is the software called Zeitgeist called that.**

[aking1012](https://askubuntu.com/users/5768/aking1012)'s [quite good answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/180994/22949) explains quite well that the software Zeitgeist is named after the [German word zeitgeist](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zeitgeist) (which it turns out has also [come into English in its own right](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeitgeist)), and has nothing to do with the film series by the same name. This answer has 7 upvotes, and I presume would be accepted if the question were reopened. I see [no reason not to reopen the question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3982/how-do-we-handle-edits-that-seem-to-intentionally-add-inflammatory-language#comment5996_3988), now that it's clear it **is** a question, and the form of the question is such that no one appears to be objecting to it.

**If you disagree, please answer explaining why. Otherwise I suggest that people who have enough reputation to cast close and reopen votes on questions cast their reopen votes.** (Or if no one objects, it would probably be quite acceptable for a moderator to simply reopen the question, as is sometimes done in this sort of situation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, I see no issues with that question. It's not a great one but its a question. I blame the pigeons on this.

I would like to see some editing on the answer though linking to more information about what is Zeitgeist for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

**The question has been reopened, so this is now resolved.**

- However, if anyone thinks it should not have been reopened or otherwise wants to discuss this, please of course feel free to post your own answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Why re-open the question? It was a borderline question to begin with and has an answer now. Just because a question is closed doesn't make it's answers any less valid.

Comment: Why not? Is there a issue with re-opening questions just because they had a troublesome start? What difference does it make now that the answer is open? I see no issues here: edits have been done, answer has been given. All the close votes that question took was before the edits, if the community still wants it closed the the votes begin now that it has been fixed.